# Cant got csrf through cors on Sails.js

Tags: sails.js

I want to use Sails.js extensible project with auth, login, & password recovery with Vue.js frontend app. But I ran into the next problem: 
I can't get a csrf token from sails api. On official manual said that should be router to action which generates csrf token:

```
{
  "GET /csrfToken": { action: "security/grant-csrf-token" }
}
```

But no any info about methods to generate it. On built-in sails view's csrf turns out from view local <%= _csrf %>.
Is it possible to get csrf token from sails.js builted-in csrf module through cors? And what way be right to use sails.js with another frontend project: use extensible sails.js project with auth, login, & password recovery, or assemble authorization functionality on empty sails.js app?

Comment: Whenever you make a new action in sails you have to `sails run rebuild-cloud-sdk`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, in the config/security.js file, you have `csrf: true`, the tokens should automatically be generated. In the action, try logging `this.req.session`, and you should see a csrfSecret that gets generated.

Comment: Yes, it is. But when Im trying to paste it in  PUT/POST request X-CSRF-Token header,  the response comes as 'FORBIDDEN'.